# overlay divs on scroll with diffent background image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have full screen divs that overlay each other on scroll, I have also added a full screen background image, but I need put  a different background image in every `div` and keep the overlay effect, if I put an image as background to div two and three the effect is lost

this is the code with i have been trying

```js
var _window = $(window),
          panels = $('.panel'),
          panelsY = [];

      // Cache position of each panel
      $.each(panels, function(i, el) {
          panelsY.push(panels.eq(i).offset().top);
      });

      // Bind our function to window scroll
      _window.bind('scroll', function() {
          updateWindow();
      });

      // Update the window
      function updateWindow() {
          var y = _window.scrollTop();

          // Loop through our panel positions
          for (i = 0, l = panels.length; i < l; i++) {
              /*
                  Firstly, we break if we're checking our last panel,
                  otherwise we compare if he y position is in between
                  two panels
              */
              if ((i === l - 1) || (y >= panelsY[i] && y <= panelsY[i+1])) {
                  break;
              }
          };

          // Update classes
          panels.not(':eq(' + i + ')').removeClass('panel-fixed');
          panels.eq(i).addClass('panel-fixed');
      };
```

```css
.bg {
    background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/800?random");
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: zoom 10s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
  
  .bg2 {
    background-image: url("https://molinocafe.com/modules/tm_imageslider/views/img/afd1e4768091d851c956b7c65f38870aa973d6cc_main.png");
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: zoom 10s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }

  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .panel {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .panel-fixed {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .panel-inner {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .panel-fixed .panel-inner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  /* Base */
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .panel-two {
    background-image: url("https://molinocafe.com/modules/tm_imageslider/views/img/afd1e4768091d851c956b7c65f38870aa973d6cc_main.png")
  }

  .panel-three {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"
  integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<body>
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="panel panel-one">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui
        hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
        montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros
        vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg2">sdasdasdas</div>
  <div class="panel panel-two">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>
        Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui
        hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
        montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros
        vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-three">
    <div class="panel-inner">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>
        Donec id ipsum odio. Cras accumsan consectetur nibh, vitae pretium dui
        hendrerit sed. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
        montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ac orci elit. Nunc faucibus eros
        vulputate purus aliquam vel blandit ligula pharetra.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me where you are having problems with. Are you asking how to add a background image to `.panel-two` and `.panel-three`?

Comment: @Lapskaus not exactly, I need keep the overlay effect with different backgorund image, if I put a image as backgoud the effect is lost

Comment: I don't see a difference in the effect when using images vs colors as background